# How To Display multiple result based on file_get_contents coming from a textarea field?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to build a multiple text domain searcher however I end up getting only one result. I have a textarea field where you can add multiple domain and a text field where you can input text.
for example I have multiple domains and paste it to the textarea field

```
abc.com/dog.txt  
def.com/cat.txt
ghi.com/mice.txt
jkl.com/bug.txt
```

then I put a keyword 'cute' in the text field the result should be

```
record found on abc.com    
record found on def.com    
record not found on  ghi.com    
record not found on jkl.com
```

**Search.php**

```
    <label>URL</label><br/>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="10" name="domainlist" id="domainlist" placeholder="Add Your Domain here seperated by comma"></textarea><br/>
    <label>Keyword</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" placeholder="Keyword " />
    <input type="submit">    

</form>
```

**Result.php**

```
$domainlist = htmlspecialchars($_POST['domainlist']);
$keyword = $_POST["keyword"];   

$file = file_get_contents('http://' .$domainlist); 
$searchnum = $keyword ; 

if (stripos($file, $searchnum) !== false) { 


    echo 'record found on'   .$domainlist;


} 

else {


    echo 'record not found' .$domainlist ;
}
```

how do I display multiple result?

Comment: And......?????? Is there a question?

Comment: question repharse

Answer (score 0):

```
$domainlist = array(
    abc.com/dog.txt  
    def.com/cat.txt
    ghi.com/mice.txt
    jkl.com/bug.txt
);
$keyword = $_POST["keyword"]; 
foreach($domainlist as $domain) {
    $file = file_get_contents('http://' . $domain);
    $searchnum = $keyword ; 

    if (stripos($file, $searchnum) !== false) { 
        echo 'record found on'   .$domain;
    } 
    else {
        echo 'record not found' .$domain;
    }
}
```

If your `$domainlist` needs to come from the browser (via POST), then you will need to pass it as an array using multiple elements with the same name like:

```
<input name="domainlist[]" value="abc.com/dog.txt" />
<input name="domainlist[]" value="def.com/cat.txt" />
```

There are other ways you could handle your `$domainlist` using javascript or some form of serialization or json object.